# copy file into directory based on filename

Tags: batch-file

I have thousands of files to move.

I have already used a batch file to create the directories I need.

My file names look like this:

- 6711_05_12.pdf
- 10504_06_15.pdf
- 559_07_11.pdf

The first characters up to the "_" are the directory the files need to go into. Started the batch file - but don't know how to identify the file name.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%I in (*.pdf) do (
 xcopy ???
)
```

Is there a manual for batch files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need a batch file. The following one line command will do the trick.

```
for %I in (*.pdf) do @for /f "eol=_ delims=_" %A in ("%I") do @copy "%I" "%A"
```

Simply double up the percents if you want to put the command in a batch file.

Comment: The command line works great! Doubling up the percents didn't work in the batch file though. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why `eol=_`? Wouldn't just `delims=_` be enough? I mean, I'm just trying to learn, I've never used `eol` in my scripts.

Comment: @AndriyM - So that it does not matter what character the file name starts with. The default EOL is `;`, which is valid in a file name. It is extremely unlikely, but a file name could begin with `;`. Setting EOL to one of the DELIMS chars effectively disables EOL.

Comment: What a great thing to know! Don't remember reading it in the built-in help, thanks!